# How to make constant raster angle on Flashprint 5?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, flashforge-creator, flashprint

I use "Flashprint 5" as a 3D print pre-processing software. I want to have a 0-degree raster angle for all its layers (100 % infill density), in the attached object below. But what I found is that each layer always alternates to 90 degrees. Any solution for this case?

[image: Raster Angle 0 degree (above) and 90 degree (below)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Flashprint expert mode, I don't seem to find options to change this.

> Any solution for this case?

Yes there is by using a different slicer, e.g. Ultimaker Cura. In Cura you will be able to specify the directions of the infill layers as you want them to be using the `Infill Line Directions` printing property. Default the property is empty (`[  ]`), but could be changed to `[90, 90]` or `[0, 0]` (or any other arbitrary angle).

Print option is found under `Infill`:
[image]

Layer 60:
[image]

Layer 61:
[image]

You can take this even further in Cura by specifying directions for more than 2 layers, e.g. `[-45, 0, 45, 90]` will give you an alternating pattern of 4 layers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, enlightened!